# How do I insert array items, parsed with forEach, into a string, using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, foreach

I have an array with values that I want to dynamically insert into a string that, in turn, is part of an `innerHTML` string. I have worked out how to parse the array items using `forEach` but I can't work out how to take the values `forEach` returns and insert them into the string.

The purpose of this is to replace the following, very inefficient, code (you can ignore the fact that the current code uses `iframe`, it isn't directly relevant to my question):

```
let container = document.querySelector('.container');
let btnLoad50 = document.getElementById('btn50');
let btnLoad51 = document.getElementById('btn51');
let btnLoad53 = document.getElementById('btn53');

btnLoad50.addEventListener('click', function( btnFunc ) {
  container.innerHTML = '<iframe src="pages/_route50.php" title="Route 50" width="900px" height="900px">';
})

btnLoad51.addEventListener('click', function( btnFunc ) {
  container.innerHTML = '<iframe src="pages/_route51.php" title="Route 51" width="900px" height="900px">';
})

btnLoad53.addEventListener('click', function( btnFunc ) {
  container.innerHTML = '<iframe src="pages/_route53.php" title="Route 53" width="900px" height="900px">';
})
```

The underlying HTML that I am targeting is this:

```
<p>Some unrelated text.</p>

  <div class="btn_div">
      <button name="load" class="btn">Click This</button>
    </div>

  <div class="container">
    <p>Something will be added here</p>
  </div>
```

This is what I've come up with so far:

This part works from the perspective that it parses the array using the `forEach` method and logs out a correctly iterated list of items in the console:

```
const rList = [50, 51, 53];
const btn = document.querySelector('.btn');
const container = document.querySelector('.container');

const routes = rList.forEach(e => console.log(`This is btn${e}`));
```

The following section gives me a `ul` list when I click the button **but** the content of each item is `This is route btnundefined` instead of `This is route btn50`, `This is route btn51`, etc:

```
btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
  container.innerHTML = `
      <ul>
        <li>This is route btn${routes}</li>
        <li>This is route btn${routes}</li>
        <li>This is route btn${routes}</li>
      </ul>`;
});
```

How can I bring it all together here? My desired outcome is the following:

1. Parse the array, return the items in the array as values;
2. Pass the items to my `eventListener` function, creating a `ul` list in the `container` element in my page with incremented `btn + item` strings.

**I'm looking for a vanilla JavaScript solution here.** While I appreciate help from JQuery pros, I'm not using JQuery for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) always returns `undefined`.Iif you want to return array of values you have to use `map`:

```js
const rList = [50, 51, 53];
const routes = rList.map(e => `This is btn${e}`);

console.log(routes);
```

or use `forEach` but do sth like:

```js
const rList = [50, 51, 53];
let routes = []
rList.forEach(e => routes.push(`This is btn${e}`));
console.log(routes);
```

When you have routes populated render data on click using map again:

```js
const rList = [50, 51, 53];
const routes = rList.map(e => `This is btn${e}`);
const btn = document.querySelector('.btn');
const container = document.querySelector('.container');


btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
  container.innerHTML = `
    <ul>
      ${routes.map(route => `<li>${route}</li>`).join('')}
    </ul>`;
});
```

```html
<p>Some unrelated text.</p>

<div class="btn_div">
    <button name="load" class="btn">Click This</button>
  </div>

<div class="container">
  <p>Something will be added here</p>
</div>
```

**EDIT:** as request by OP in comment.
I would use `forEach` this way, but in this case I really do think that `map` works jus better. I rarely use `forEach` or naked `for` loops for data transforamtion. If ind `map`, `filter` and `reduce` superior in cases like this.

```js
btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
  let htmlString = `<ul>`;
  routes.forEach(route => htmlString +=`<li>${route}</li>`);
  htmlString += </ul>`;
  container.innerHTML = htmlString;
});
```

Comment: I'm not sure that gets me closer to my goal of taking those array items/values and inserting them into my innerHTML strings, though? Any suggestions there?

Comment: Ok, great. I clearly misunderstood the `map` method and how I was using `forEach`. So, in your code, the `routes` variable now contains the dynamic string?

Comment: Would you mind clarifying what is happening in this line for me? I'm not sure I understand it fully:

${routes.map(route => `<li>${route}</li>`).join('')}

Comment: Using array of routes (`route`) you create another array of `li` strings and then you join them to get one string, which finally is put in your innerHtml string.

Comment: Does anything else need clarification? Does this answer help you?

Comment: It does help me, thank you. Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156102/discussion-between-paul-jacobson-and-andrzej-smyk).

Comment: Would you mind sharing your event listener solution with the `forEach` option too? I'm curious how that would work.